# Makita Power tools identification help

Tags: powertools

I hope I am in the right stackexchange domain for this question.

I have acquired an old Makita SDS-MAX drill hammer in a garage sale for almost nothing because the rotor of the electrical engine is fried.
The issue is that the print with the tool reference is gone, and the series number are not helping me find anything on the internet. Moreover, Makita is now producing a new version of this tool so it is even listed on their website.

My question is thus : could you help me identify this powertool so that I can find the right part for it ? Thanks !
The details :

- it is a Makita drill hammer for Europe (220 V)
- the bits are SDS Max
- There a two positions : hammer or drill hammer
- It is probably ten years old but I can't say for sure.

Here's a picture 
[image]

Comment: it may be a Demolition Hammer

Comment: look for any part numbers on any of the parts .... if you find one, it may point you to the model number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is a Makita HR4010C, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It is a HR4000C. Found the same on a classified ads website and the picture is a match =)